# Picasso context is null

Tags: android, json, listview, picasso

I have the following problem, i am trying to create a listview with images which i get from a server. I pass on the url and it should spit out the images in the list. this and everything is working correctly. I am using the following bit of code

```
public class ParseJSON extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL_BASE = "";

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    JSONArray mJsonArray;

    public ParseJSON(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {

        mContext  = context;
        mInflater = inflater;
        mJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    }
```

here i am trying to get the context. I have also tried to pass it from the mainactivity.java but that also isn't working. I am using it here

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(imageURL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.sportmuziek)
                    .into(holder.musicArtwork);
```

But i am keep getting that mcontext is null for some reason. I have searched and i know that i have to set the context but it should get it from the parsejson activity. But for some reason that is not possible. I have no idea how to get this working correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `this.mContext = context`.

Comment: i am going to try this, thanks

Comment: You don't need to pass both `Context` and `LayoutInflater` arguments. You can use a `Context` object to get a `LayoutInflater` with the static [`LayoutInflater.from(context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context)) method, and get a `Context` from a `LayoutInflater` with the [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#getContext()) method.

Comment: thanks for your help, however how do i place the getcontext(). I have tried several things but i am getting a cannot resolve method error at the moment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the reference you are passing is setting in the `mContext` using debugging.

if this does not help then in your `getView` function in same class you can get context directly from `ViewGroup` using

```
context = viewGroup.getContext();
```

Hope this helps you.